# ¿Como puedo crear varias hojas en ReportViewer?

Tags: reportviewer, ssrs

Estoy tratando de programar un reporte en reportviewer, que tenga diferentes hojas donde se describan diferentes calculos, por ejemplo:

En la primera hoja, numero de visitas a diferentes personas y su debido porcentaje de todas las visitas, en la segunda hoja diferentes calculos, etc., y si todo en un mismo archivo .rdlc

Si alguien sabe como realizarlo o conocen algún sitio web, estaré muy agradecido.

Saludos.